# svelte component-library intellisense for exported properties

Tags: svelte

I have created a small component-library for myself based on this GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/sveltejs/component-template

This works fine and i have uploaded it to npm.

When i want to use my components in another project i just install them and use them. This works fine as well. The only thing i don't get is Intellisense for the exported properties of my component in VSCode.

What do i have to add in my component library to get some basic Intellisense in the project where i use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SvelteComponentTyped` utility class for that:

```
declare module "myModule" {
  import { SvelteComponentTyped } from 'svelte';
  
  export class MyComponent extends SvelteComponentTyped<
    { propA: boolean },
    { someEvent: CustomEvent<string>; click: MouseEvent }> {}
}
```

### Old/Outdated answer

At the moment there is no official way yet. [This RFC](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/37) proposes a way on how to that. If it's accepted and implemented, you would write a `d.ts` definition file with something like this:

```js
import { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte';

declare module "myModule" {
  export class MyComponent extends SvelteComponent<
    { propA: boolean },
    { someEvent: CustomEvent<string>; click: MouseEvent }> {}
}
```

If you don't want to wait you can copy over the definition [from here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/svelte2tsx/svelte-shims.d.ts#L5), which is likely to become the official type definition, and switch it out later - but you have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `svelte.config.js` file to your projects-root dir.
Highlighting, code-complete and other things can be configured for css, html and js/ts.

Have a look at:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JamesBirtles.svelte-vscode